# Servlet returning &quot; to AngularJS2 call

Tags: java, angularjs, json, servlets

I am making a POST call using Angular2 to a servlet.  I must use a servlet for now.  The servlet is returning JSON in the response but Angular shows all responses as failures due to the response containing

```
&quot;
```

in the JSON response instead of ".  I'm seeing this in the console:

```
xhrstatusText: {&quot;status&quot;:&quot;OK&quot;}
replaced statusTest={"status":"OK"}
```

I'm not sure if the problem is with the servlet or Angular call.

Servlet

```
public void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {    
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    JsonObject jsonObj = Json.createObjectBuilder().add("status", "OK").build();
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK, jsonObj.toString());
}
```

Angular2 POST call

```
makeFileRequest(params: Array<string>, files: Array<File>) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var formData: any = new FormData();
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            formData.append("uploads[]", files[i], files[i].name);
        }

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                // Contains &quot; instead of " in JSON.
                console.log('xhrstatusText: ' + xhr.statusText);
                // This fixes the JSON, but the response is already marked as failed.
                var statusTextJson = xhr.statusText.replace(/(&quot\;)/g,"\"");
                console.log('replaced statusTest=' + statusTextJson);

                if (xhr.status == 200) {
                    resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                } else {
                    reject(xhr.response);
                }
            }
        }

        xhr.open("POST", this.url, true);
        xhr.send(formData);
    });
}
```

!!! FINAL SOLUTION !!!

Servlet

```
public void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {    
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    JsonObject jsonObj = Json.createObjectBuilder().add("status", "OK").build();
    response.getWriter().println(jsonObj.toString());
}
```

Angular2 POST call

```
makeFileRequest(params: Array<string>, files: Array<File>) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var formData: any = new FormData();
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            formData.append("uploads[]", files[i], files[i].name);
        }

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                // {"status":"OK"}
                console.log('xhr.response: ' + xhr.response);

                if (xhr.status == 200) {
                    resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                } else {
                    reject(xhr.response);
                }
            }
        }

        xhr.open("POST", this.url, true);
        xhr.send(formData);
    });
}
```

Comment: You're sending the response as the text of the status rather than sending it as the body of the response. Moreover, sending {"status": "OK"} is kind of useless. That's what the HTTP status 200 means already. Also, why don't you use the Angular2 Http service, instead of this low-level, non-portable, messy xhr code?

Comment: @JBNizet I get the impression that this is for an assignment, given the "I must use a servlet for now" requirement. I don't think this code is intended to be very practical. Agreed on the Angular2 point though.

Comment: No assignment.  I'm converting a production UI to Angular2/JAX-RS (from  jsp/Servlets) and I'm under a deadline.  I've converted all servlets to JAX-RS except for the one which supports uploading files.  I'm going to use the servlet for uploading files for now until I solve my JAS-RS issues.

Comment: 1) I'm using 200 for testing.  What I really need is to to send back information when the call fails (e.g. the file upload failed (400) because of missing information) so the user knows why it failed.  So the returned JSON on a 400 status will be something like {"error":"Missing name"}.

2) I'm using XMLHttpRequest because it's the only code I've been able to get to work for uploading files.

Answer (score 1):

Per the javadocs for [HttpServletResponse](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html), the `setStatus(int, String)` method has actually been deprecated for this very reason (ambiguity of second argument purpose). It was not really intended to do what you are attempting to do.

Instead, consider simply setting the status with the `setStatus(int)` method and writing your JsonObject to the response's print writer:

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
response.getWriter().println(jsonObj.toString());
```

Comment: This works.  I tried this before and found it doesn't cause an error in Angular2, but I didn't see the JSON in the Angular2 xhr that the servlet returned.  The returned JSON is in the reponse as a JSON object.

Comment: Why are you calling it Angular2 xhr? The javascript code you posted to do the actual request has very little to do with Angular2. You should be using the $http service as JB Nizet mentioned in the comment on your question.

Comment: Corrected wording: This works. I tried this before and found it doesn't cause an error in the XMLHttpRequest, but I didn't see the JSON in the  XMLHttpRequest that the servlet returned. The returned JSON is in the reponse as a string.

Comment: Ok. I might have misunderstood what you were attempting to do. I'm not sure why you are attempting to use JSON in your status text (especially for a 200). I'm not sure my answer actually applies for what you are trying to do. And I'll say that you probably shouldn't be doing what you are trying to do.

Comment: What do you suggest?  My requirement is simple.  I need to upload a file, along with a couple of other pieces of text from a form and return a status and error text if the upload fails.